# D3.js Multiple Line Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I tried to show my two Line Chart using D3.js,

I can display the first chart "blob",

But it doesn't work with "blub"!!

How can I fix it and how to simplify the for loop?

```js
var canvas=d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width",500).attr("height",300);

var donnees= {
    blob:[
      {x:10,y:20},{x:20,y:60}, {x:30,y:70},
      {x:40,y:202},{x:50,y:260}, {x:60,y:70},
      {x:70,y:75},{x:80,y:70}, {x:90,y:0}
    ],
    blub:[
      {x:100,y:20},{x:110,y:20},{x:120,y:60}, {x:130,y:70},
      {x:140,y:32},{x:150,y:60}, {x:160,y:90},
      {x:170,y:75},{x:180,y:100}, {x:190,y:20}
    ]
};


var groupe= canvas.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,20)");
var line= d3.svg.line()
    .x (function(d){return d.x})
    .y (function(d){return d.y});
var colors = d3.scale.category20();

var index = 0;
for (var i in donnees) {
 groupe.selectAll("path")
    .data([donnees[i]])
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d",line)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", colors(index))
    .attr("stroke-width","1");

index++
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try creating the `d3.svg.line()` inside the for..in loop and attach the data to it.
Atm you're only creating one line I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you don't need a loop here (you almost never do in D3), but you can use [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest):

```
groupe.selectAll("g")
  .data(d3.values(donnees))
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(function(d) { return [d]; })
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  ...
```

The problem you're seeing specifically is because you're selecting `path` elements, which, after the first iteration of the loop, will be there already. That is, the data you provide in `.data()` is matched by the existing `path` element and hence the `.enter()` selection is empty, adding nothing. You can work around this e.g. by assigning a class to each `path` that allows you to distinguish them, but a better solution is to use nested selection as I've outlined above.

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g1r5gsfy/1).

See [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles) for more details on how selections work.

Comment: Hi Lars, I tried what you say, but nothing happens. Could you edit this link please : https://jsfiddle.net/g1r5gsfy/

Comment: Ah, a forgotten `.enter()` and some data conversions. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help;

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using data() and enter(), i directly appended the path tag to g tag which worked for me.

```
            var canvas=d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",500).attr("height",300);

var donnees= {
    blob:[
      {x:10,y:20},{x:20,y:60}, {x:30,y:70},
      {x:40,y:202},{x:50,y:260}, {x:60,y:70},
      {x:70,y:75},{x:80,y:70}, {x:90,y:0}
    ],
    blub:[
      {x:100,y:20},{x:110,y:20},{x:120,y:60}, {x:130,y:70},
      {x:140,y:32},{x:150,y:60}, {x:160,y:90},
      {x:170,y:75},{x:180,y:100}, {x:190,y:20}
    ]
};


var groupe= canvas.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,20)");
var line= d3.svg.line()
    .x (function(d){ return d.x})
    .y (function(d){return d.y});
var colors = d3.scale.category20();

var index = 0;
for (var i in donnees) {
    groupe
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", line(donnees[i]))
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", colors(index))
    .attr("stroke-width", 1);

index++
}
```